# Нахождение суммы элементов и длины вложенных списков в двумерном массиве. Python

Tags: python, матрицы

У меня есть двумерный список с произвольным количеством и значением чисел (элементы каждый раз разные):

```
arr = [
[2, 4, 6],
[10, 21, 5, 4],
[1, 2]
]
```

Мне нужно найти количество и сумму элементов каждого вложенного списка по отдельности, не используя функции `len()` и `sum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого Вы можете использовать вложенные циклы(код даже не запускал, доделывайте)

```js
arr = [
[2, 4, 6],
[10, 21, 5, 4],
[1, 2]
]

result_count = []
result_sum = []

for el in arr:
    # Перебираем список
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for i in el:
        # Перебираем вложенный список
        sum += i
        count += 1
        # Здесь забирайте Ваши значения, как Вам надо
        
        # Пример:
    result_count.append(count)
    result_sum.append(sum)
```

**Важно!**

Я очень надеюсь, что Ваше решение не использовать `sum()` и `len()` полностью оправданно. Если же у Вас просто затруднения с ними, я советую их использовать

Вот намного упрощенный код, рекомендую делать так:

```js
arr = [
[2, 4, 6],
[10, 21, 5, 4],
[1, 2]
]

result_count = []
result_sum = []

for el in arr:
    # Перебираем список
    result_count.append(len(el)) # Просто забираем длину
    result_sum.append(sum(el)) # Забираем сумму
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
def sumlen(elem):
    col=0
    summa=0
    for i in elem:
        col+=1
        summa+=i
    return col, summa
for i in arr:
    print(sumlen(i))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]